# Continuous Building on Linux

Tags: linux, build, continuous-integration

We have a smallish C++ Linux project that accompanies our large C++/MFC Windows project.  Currently, the Windows project uses CruiseControl.net and Visual Build Pro for managing continuous building and integration.  We would like implement something to start our Linux project on the same path.

My question is, should I research using a separate Build tool for Linux or attempt to get Visual Build Pro to work by leveraging its automation and simply invoking a make script on a our Linux Build Machine to actually compile the project?

Even further, due to the size of the Linux project, would it be just easier to script it all including making snapshots and such?

Comment: this might be better suited on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jenkins or hudson to build on Linux box. This tools have integration with Source Control (svn, perforce, ...), cppunit ...

Answer (score 3):

While I don't know the complexity of the "integration" step in your project, the "building" step is in my experience best solved by a trivial shell script:

```
 BUILDDIR=`mktemp -d`
 svn checkout MY_REPOSITORY/trunk $BUILDDIR
 cd $BUILDDIR
 ./configure
 make all check
```

I've solved the integration test part with Dejagnu in my current project, works like a charm with another line of sh calling it.

Then insert this shell script into the daily run routine (e.g. by adding it to the `crontab` of a special CI user on the Linux machine) and forward all of the mail the CI user gets to the person responsible for watching the CI.

Comment: The other issue I failed to mention is they like CruiseControl because you can just load up the website, force a build, check logs for errors and such.  I think the idea is to continue this sort of usage.  It was my understanding that CC.net won't work with Linux but I could be entirely wrong.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Robb: This is a little like buying a car to replace a scooter and then asking to keep braking by stepping firmly on the rearwheel. Drop any website stuff, ssh is just so much easier to set up and maintain.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment but the powers that be differ.  Anyways, I will consider this solution at it seems trivial to maintain, easier than I thought.